# Error adding virtual applications via powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Having issues adding Azure Virtual Applications

We're trying to add azure virtual applications within our CI/CD pipeline via referencing a powershell script (This is within Azure DevOps' product).  I've built a container with all the underlying framework, which I've been testing on.  However, this part is borking the entire process, and we can't seem to make headway on a resolution or workaround.

First attempt:

```bsh
$ArrayList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList `
>> $ArrayList.Add((Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.VirtualApplication("/Customer", "si
te\wwwroot\Customer")))

Error:
Add-Type : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:2 char:17
+ ... ayList.Add((Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSite ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Type], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

$ArrayList.Add((Add-Type -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.VirtualApplication("/Customer", "site\wwwroot\Customer")))
```

Second direction:

```bsh
Error:
Add-Type : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TypeName'.
At line:2 char:26
+ $ArrayList.Add((Add-Type -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSite ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Type], ParameterBindingExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. 
   AddTypeCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-Type cmdlet takes types in the specified assembly, this cmdlet does not have return value. You need to call New-Object cmdlet to instantiate the types. 
You can check the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6) for more information

Below scripts is only for reference:

```
Add-Type –AssemblyName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites
$VA = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.VirtualApplication -ArgumentList ("/Customer", "si
te\wwwroot\Customer") 
$ArrayList.Add($VA)
```

Add-Type cmdlet does not work on my powershell for some reason. Instead I add the assembly using `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(path to assembly.dll)`. You can use `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom()` if `add-type` throws error ‘Unable to load…..”.